# Interfacing arduino due to MAX5724 DAC

Tags: arduino-due

I have a MAX5724 8 channel 10 bit DAC's connected to a due, i believe i have it wired up correctly, however when  i try to write a value to it doesn't seem to output anything. Either i misunderstood the datasheet in the wiring or im writing incorrectly to it. Since i have the LDAC connected to GND i think i can just use the CODEn command on page 21 of the datasheet.

A link to the datasheet:
http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX5723-MAX5725.pdf

Here the code i use to write:

```
#include <SPI.h>

#define CS 52

void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(115200);
  SPI.begin(CS);
  SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);
  SPI.setDataMode(CS, 1);
  SPI.setClockDivider(CS, 3); // 28MHz
  pinMode(CS, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CS, LOW);
  

 byte msg1 = 0b11000010; 
 byte msg2 = 0b11111111;
 byte msg3 = 0b11111111;


 SPI.transfer(CS,msg1,SPI_CONTINUE);
 SPI.transfer(CS,msg2,SPI_CONTINUE);
 SPI.transfer(CS,msg3,SPI_LAST);
 delay(4000);

}
```

wiring:
1 = 5V,
2 - 9 = OUTPUT,
10 = 5V,
11 = 5V,
12 = MOSI (middle pins),
13 = MISO (middle pins),
14 = SCK (middle pins),
15 = PIN 52,
16 = OUTPUT,
17 = 5V,
18 = GND,
19 = GND,
20 = GND,

Comment: I'm guessing the SAM3X didn't have enough DACs?

Comment: You swapped the MISO and MOSI. DIN should be connected to MOSI (Master Out **Slave In**). DOUT to MISO.

Comment: aye i realised my mistake, thanks a lot for you help